# Adding Arrows inside itemize in latex

Tags: latex

I want to add a long left right arrow inside itemize.
At the moment I use:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item DNS <-> check\_dns
\item DHCP <-> check\_dhcp
\end{itemize}
```

But I want something like ↔ instead of <->.

Unfurtunatly I can't use "\longleftrightarrow" cause i get "\item invalid in math mode" if I try.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is quite simple. The command "\longleftrightarrow" only works in math mode. 
The solution is thus to use inline math mode by using `\( \longleftrightarrow \)` or `$ \longleftrightarrow $`.

Your code then changes to:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item DNS **\(\longleftrightarrow\)** check\_dns
    \item DHCP **\(\longleftrightarrow\)** check\_dhcp
\end{itemize}
```

Note: if you are a new latex user and you want more information about the concept math mode, then this link could be interesting: [wikibooks about latex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Mathematics_environments)